# USB drive Dell does not work on Lubuntu

Tags: usb-drive, lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu 11.10 on Sony Vaio.

I got one USB Dell external disk 1tb as [this one](http://snpi.dell.com/snp/images/products/large/pt-br~342-5678/342-5678.jpg).

But when I connect nothing happens. (even I can feel with my hand that it is running)

From `dmesg` I got

```
[ 2758.780713] usb 2-1.3: new high speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[ 2758.935542] scsi8 : uas
[ 2758.937160] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Dell     USB Portable HDD 0412 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
```

My laptop does not have a usb 3.0 connection. Could this be the problem?

Gparted does not show it.

Some info here:

```
Aug 14 19:30:41 vaio kernel: [ 2797.116285] sd 8:0:0:4: [sdh] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
Aug 14 19:30:41 vaio kernel: [ 2797.116291] sd 8:0:0:4: rejecting I/O to offline device
Aug 14 19:30:41 vaio kernel: [ 2797.116298] sd 8:0:0:4: [sdh] Asking for cache data failed
Aug 14 19:30:41 vaio kernel: [ 2797.116303] sd 8:0:0:4: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through
Aug 14 19:30:41 vaio kernel: [ 2797.116332] sd 8:0:0:7: [sdk] Attached SCSI disk
Aug 14 19:30:41 vaio kernel: [ 2797.116507] sd 8:0:0:4: [sdh] Attached SCSI disk
Aug 14 19:30:41 vaio kernel: [ 2797.116719] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
Aug 14 19:30:41 vaio ata_id[25346]: unable to open '/dev/sdg'
Aug 14 19:30:41 vaio ata_id[25349]: unable to open '/dev/sdf'
Aug 14 19:30:41 vaio ata_id[25350]: unable to open '/dev/sdd'
Aug 14 19:30:41 vaio ata_id[25355]: unable to open '/dev/sdk'
Aug 14 19:30:41 vaio ata_id[25348]: unable to open '/dev/sde'
Aug 14 19:30:41 vaio ata_id[25356]: unable to open '/dev/sdi'
Aug 14 19:30:41 vaio ata_id[25353]: unable to open '/dev/sdh'
Aug 14 19:30:41 vaio ata_id[25354]: unable to open '/dev/sdj'
```

Comment: Looks like its connection is intermittent; I'll hazard a guess and say it doesn't get enough power from the USB port.  Have you tired a) a different port or b) can you power it via an adapter?

Comment: I tried all the four USB connectors and no success. I can feel some vibration inside it. What do you mean with *via an adapter*? The drive does have only one connector to insert its USB cable.

Comment: E.g. a powered USB HUB. I've seen a few cases w/ different laptop models where the ports didn't provide enough power for a USB only device to function.

Answer (score 1):

### Partial solution

I discovered that blocking `uas` fixes the problem. I just added `blacklist uas` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf 
blacklist uas
```